# Loop using count + modulo (when applicable) in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To break up a long migration of data, I'm using a query limited to groups of 100, then processing those 100 records.

#### something like this...

```
count = Model.where("conditions").count
count = count / 100
count = count+1 if count%100 != 0
count.times do
  #do my data migration steps .limit(100)...
end
```

is there a shortcut or better way of doing that count based on whether or not there is a remainder when dividing by 100? Feels like I'm forgetting an easy way (besides rounding which seems slower, but maybe it's not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is very well supported by Rails, you do not have to roll your own code for finding batches of records.

The easiest is to simply use [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html), which seamlessly loads 1000 records at a time:

```
Model.find_each do |model|
  # ...
end
```

The underlying mechanism is [`find_in_batches`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) with a default batch size of 1000. You can use `find_in_batches` directly, but you do not have to, `find_each` is sufficient:

```
Model.find_in_batches(batch_size: 100) do |batch|
  batch.each do |model|
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I knew there was something I was forgetting about that made this much easier. Thank you for such a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rails has several methods for loading records in [batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html).  `find_each` would work nicely here. It defaults to batches of 1000, but you can specify the batch size:

```
Model.find_each(batch_size: 100) do |record|
  ...
end
```